# WiX make message text bold in welcome dialog

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have a message about the product in the welcome dialog screen. In Earlier WIX 2.0 version we had to modify the WixUi_Mondo file to make the message text bold. But in WIX3.5 how to achieve this. Can anyone help me on this?

In my WiX file, I'm referring `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo"/>` this lib for the dialog screens. I'm not able to find this file in version 3.5 to modify. Is there any alternative way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to customize the WiX default dialogs, you need to also download the source (for the version of the WiX binary you are using). In the source directory, the Mondo UI is located under:

> < Wix3.5 source directory >\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib

From there, the Mondo file specifies which dialogs to use for that UI model. 
It uses the welcome dialog file

> WelcomeDlg.wxs

That specifies how to display the welcome text. Its in that file, that you would make changes for font weight etc.